# SQL dump backup database

Tags: mysql, database

I want to backup my server databases if i backup all mysql databases on server1 using

```
mysqldump --all-databases
```

command, and if i restore that mysqpdump to server2,what will happen to the existing databases on server2?

so do i have to create those databases before restore?Please advice.

Comment: http://webcheatsheet.com/sql/mysql_backup_restore.php

Comment: mysqldump generates **SQL** rather than binary dumps. You can just look at it ;-)